# Unable to visualize in VMD as well as in xmgrace

Tags: macos, xmgrace, vmd

I am new to computational biology. I am using grimaces for simulating a protein. I tried visualising the protein in VMD, but failed. VMD opens, but when I select the .pdb file and click on upload, I can't see the protein. Similarly, I could create the .xvg file. But when I tried opening it in xmgrace, I obtained a graph with no plot.

Am I missing some libraries or something?

I am using Mac OS X yosemite

Thank you in advance for the kind help

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data file that you are trying to plot in xmgrace.